# cannot get layout width to be same as my text on XML

Tags: android

i have started learning xml, while i use linear layout and put its layout_width to be wrap_content and also using a layout width of my text view to be wrap_content, it covers up the entire width of my screen(width wise).

**NOTE**:- This happens only when i select orientation to be vertical. is there something i am missing?

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#D2B48C"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:text="sahil"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#DC143C"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

the above is my code.

here is the image:-
       [my xml result of the code written above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmN0I.png)

Comment: can you attach an image to show this?

Comment: @NitinTej added, please check!

Comment: I wonder why doesnt it work. The XML code seems to be pretty accurate to me. I will try it and let you know anyway

Answer (score 0):

[image]

As I can see this what your XML code result and the `TextView` width seem to be `wrap_content`. You better share your screenshot too, so that I can help.

Comment: please check my screenshot, edited the post for this!

Comment: Did you try running your code on an Emulator or a real device it should work normally?